# How to interpret Carathéodory's theorem for a twice differentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $ f(x) = |x|^3 $, compute $f'(0),f''(0),f'''(0)$.

I was trying to use Carathéodory's theorem to prove that the function is differentiable.

- **Finding $f'(0)$**

> We know that the function is differentiable at $x=0$ if there exists a $f_1(x)$ continuous at $x=0$ such that
>
> $$f(x) - f(0) = f_1(x)(x-0) \cdots (*)$$
>
> Here $f(0) = 0$. Also we know that $f(x) = x^3, x \ge 0 $ and $f(x) = -x^3,x < 0 $
>
> Then $f_1(x) = x^2 ; x \ge 0 $ and $f(x) = -x^2; x < 0$.
>
> This function $f_1(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$ and also satisfies $(*)$
>
> Hence $f'(0) = f_1(0) = 0$

- Finding $f''(0)$

**This is where I am confused. To show that $f''(0)$ exist using the Carathéodory's theorem should I show that there is a function $f_2(x)$ continuous at $x= 0 $ such that $f_1(x) - f_1(0) = f_2(x)(x-0)$ or should I show that the function $f_2(x)$ satisfies $f'(x) - f'(0) = f_2(x)(x-0) ?$**

Comment: The first one only gives existence of $f'(0)$,  you need the second one for $f''(0)$.

Comment: I don't understand - why will $f''(0 )$ not be equal to $f_2(0)$ where $f_1(x) - f_1(0) = f_2(x)(x-0)$?

Comment: $f_1(x) = f'(x)$ only at $x = 0$, so an application of Carathéodory's theorem to $f_1$ doesn't say much about $f'$.